# Spring Data does not save related entity

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

I have several entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "alIdSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "aIdSeq", sequenceName = "a_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "blIdSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "aIdSeq", sequenceName = "b_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

}
```

**Example:** When I get object A from repo and add new object B to list then repository does not save new object B.

```
A a = aRepository.findById(someId);
B b = new B();
a.getB().add(B);
```

**Note:** Sql table does not contain new B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the merge to cascade , it is set only on persist

just add `CascadeType.MERGE`

```
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that your object `a` already created, and persisted operation didn't happen.
If you try to create (persist) new entity (`A`) with some `B` elements, new `B` will contains in sql table.